# how can i access a global variable in navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers.list

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

Can someone tell me how I can access a variable that I defined on top of my script?

See example:

```
public my_variable = [];

constructor(.....

  getContacts(){
      navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers.list(function(contacts) {
        console.log(contacts.length + ' contacts found');
        for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
          console.log(contacts[i].id + " - " + contacts[i].displayName);
          for(var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
            var phone = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j];
            **// here is the problem: **null is not an object** this.my_variable**
            this.my_variable.push(phone.number);
          }
        }
      }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
     });   
  }
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Cheers

Comment: Try declaring your variable like this: `public my_variable: any [] = [];`

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable like this: `public my_variable: any [] = [];`